# Redshift ODBC Driver error: String data right truncation on data from data source: String data is too big for the driver's data buffer

Tags: c#, odbc, amazon-redshift

I am using the RedShift ODBC driver for .NET to insert rows into a RedShift database table.

The table contains a column called 'email' and defined as VARCHAR(MAX)
The rows are all inserted without issue until a row with a non-standard character (e.g. the 3/4 character or a French e with the accent mark) is inserted. At that point I get the following error:

"String data right truncation on data from data source: String data is too big for the driver's data buffer."

Here is the connection string (using string.Format to replace some of the information):

```
Driver={{Amazon Redshift (x64)}};Server={0};Database={1};UID={2};PWD={3};Port={4};SSL=true;Sslmode=Require;MaxVarchar=1000;UseUnicode=1"
```

I added the last two parameters in order to see if they would help, but without them it also doesn't work.

Additional info: When I insert the row using a client program like "Aginity", the rows are inserted property, leading me to believe that the problem is not with the table definition.

Here is the insert that works in the client program (the email is intentionally not a legal email):

```
insert into summary.member values ('59D6687E-078F-45EA-8736-9A08AA85AD4D', 'shrew8@gmail¾comdde')
```

Here is the table definition:

CREATE TABLE summary.member
(
 member_id VARCHAR(255) DISTKEY,
 member_email VARCHAR(255)
)
SORTKEY
(
 member_id,
 member_email
);

Here is the code which opens the connection:

> private static OdbcConnection CreateAndOpenOdbcConnection()
>           {
>               const string server = "someserverinfo.redshift.amazonaws.com";
>               const string port = "5439";
>               const string masterUsername = "myusername";
>               const string masterUserPassword = "mypassword";
>               const string dbName = "databasename";

```
        var connectionString =
            string.Format(
                "Driver={{Amazon Redshift (x64)}};Server={0};Database={1};UID={2};PWD={3};Port={4};SSL=true;Sslmode=Require;MaxVarchar=1000;UseUnicode=1",
                server, dbName, masterUsername, masterUserPassword, port);
        var odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
        odbcConnection.Open();
        return odbcConnection;
    }
```

Here is the code that does the insert:

> ```
>    private int InsertMember(Guid column1data, string column2data)
>     {
>         var command = new OdbcCommand(string.Format("INSERT INTO database.table (column1, column2, column3) values(?, ?, ?)"), Connection);
>         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column1", column1data.ToString());
>         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column2", column2data);
>         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column3", "column3data");
>         return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
>     }
> ```

Comment: Can you also include the table definition you're using?

Comment: I added the table definition to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: And are you using the new RedShift ODBC drivers from Amazon (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-postgres-jdbc.html) or the old Postgres ones?

Comment: I'm using the new RedShift ODBC drivers

Comment: Thanks for adding the table definition, I notice you only have two columns in the table def but 3 in the INSERT. Was that just a typo?

Comment: I tested the driver and wasn't able to reproduce this, note that UseUnicode was enabled in the DSN. Are you able to post your C# code that causes the problem?

Comment: Yes @KylePorter. That was a typo. I've updated the question with the source code you requested.

Comment: there're still three columns in your insert in the code, did your table definition have 3 columns originally or does your code try to insert 3 columns into a table with 2 columns?

Comment: This appears to be, oddly enough, a bug in the ADO.NET to ODBC bridge, where if a property for the VARCHAR conversions is reported to say that conversions to WVARCHAR is supported, the bridge will truncate the length when binding. The Postgres driver doesn't report this, so the bridge doesn't truncate the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround to this issue is to use the PostgreSQL UNICODE driver instead of the RedShift one. It seems there might be a bug in the RedShift driver which causes this behavior. I've informed AWS support and they are looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has released an update to their ODBC driver to resolve this issue:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/install-odbc-driver-windows.html